# Sending a pdf from public folder in express

Tags: express

I am trying to serve a PDF by adding watermark to it. I am using the image-watermark package for it

```
    let option ={'text' : 'hello','color' : 'rgb(154, 50, 46)'};
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
    fs.createReadStream(watermark.embedWatermark('/pdf/js_tut.pdf', option)).pipe(res);
```

I am confused at what i did wrong? I am getting a 500 error. did I put the path name wrong?  I have a public folder inside which I have a pdf folder inside which i have js_tut.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the function `embedWatermark`, it doesn't actually return anything. You can see that [here](https://github.com/luthraG/image-watermark/blob/master/watermark.js#L178).

There is not a single `return` statement anywhere there.

So essentially what you're doing is this:

```
fs.createReadStream(undefined).pipe(res)
```

Which is likely why you're getting `500`.